# JSON.parse throws syntax error with string created by JSON.stringify

Tags: json, parsing

I'm passing a JSON.stringify message through RabbitMQ.  It appears that by the time it makes it through rabbit, it is no longer something JSON.parse can read.

```
sendNodeCreated(JSON.stringify({UID:"sdflkjh45", NAME:"Node 71", X:45, Y:54}));
```

At the other end, I receive a string:

```
{"UID":"sdflkjh45","NAME":"Node 71","X":45,"Y":54}
```

When I call JSON.parse on this string, I get

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token s
at Object.parse (native)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.  This message parses fine in the python app I am running, and JSONlint says it's valid.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing a string to `JSON.parse` on the other end? The information you provided is not sufficient to solve the problem.

Comment: How are you calling `JSON.parse()`? Is it being called with data from an AJAX call from jQuery for example? Cause jQuery and other frameworks already parse the data for you depending on the way you called the AJAX function.

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString())`

When I `console.log(msg.content.toString())` I get:

  `{"UID":"sdflkjh45","NAME":"Node 71","X":45,"Y":54}`

The message contents parse fine with simplejson in python.  The application is using amqplib in node.js

Answer (score 0):

Well, I force_reset rabbitmq, and now everything is working as it should.  Hopefully this persists.

Comment: Can u elebrate it more in details by offering us a solution and mark yours as an answer?

Comment: I never figured out the cause of the problem, but it did stop happening.  It remains a mystery to me to this day.